# Grub 2 can't boot Ubuntu 16.04 automatically

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2

I have only one OS in my laptop and it is Ubuntu 16.04.

When I turn on my laptop I have to boot Ubuntu by command line like

[image]

How can I boot Ubuntu automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: You are showing grub 1.99, but 16.04 should be a 2.02 version. Looks like when you reinstalled, you did not install grub to MBR. Be sure to use one of the options to totally reinstall grub to fully correct it.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I just use of commands of this picture for booting. my grub is version 2.